# C++ Initializing array member with a length known by constructor at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm writing code for a display on an embedded device that displays screens, each with some amount of buttons. The amount of buttons differs between screens, but the amount is known at compile time.

Right now, here's a simplified version of how the classes are set up:

```
class Button;

class Screen {
private:
    Button *buttons;
    unsigned int buttonCount;
public:
    Screen(Button *_buttons, unsigned int _buttonCount)
        : button(_buttons), buttonCount(_buttonCount) {}
};
```

And here's an idea of how I've used them:

```
// For this example, Button has a constructor taking a string for
// the button's label
static Button buttonsForMainMenu[] = {
    Button("Do this"),
    Button("Do that"),
    Button("Exit")
};

Screen mainMenu (buttonsForMainMenu, 3);

Screen *currentScreen = &mainMenu;

int main() {
    // ...
    while (1) {
        currentScreen->show();
        // handle buttons, etc.
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid having a separate array for buttons. Ideally, something like this:

```
Screen mainMenu ({
    Button("Do this"),
    Button("Do that"),
    Button("Exit")
});
```

This code is for an embedded system that hasn't needed dynamic memory allocation, so I'd like to keep avoiding that. `std::array` needs the array size at its declaration within the class declaration, but the Screens will have different amounts of Buttons. The Screen class I don't believe can be templated because of `currentScreen`.

Is there a way for a class to have an array where the array size is found at its declaration/at compile-time?

Comment: Please edit your question to be clearer about what you're asking because it's kind of hard to decipher. What's wrong with `std::array<type, 3>`?

Comment: @AndyG I believe, because OP doesn't want to specify the size of the array in it's type, and wants it to be driven by the number of arguments to the constructor.

Comment: If I understood the requirements correctly (see my comment above), I am afraid, there is no really nice syntax you can use. You'd have to put the number of elements in the `std::array` as a type, and you can have an assert in your constructor to make sure the number of arguments matches the size of the vector.

Comment: The size of character literals can be deduced at compile time like this: `const char x = "xyz";  constexpr size_t size_of_array = sizeof(x) / sizeof (char);`

Comment: @AndyG edited, hope that helps, and @SergeyA is right. `std::array` would work if I did something like `std::array<Button, MAX_BUTTON_COUNT>`, but that would waste memory.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how is this expected to help OP?

Comment: @SergeyA How it actually isn't? The obvios way is to use a template class, and involve `sizeof(x)` for a template parameter.

Comment: @clyne worse than waste the memory, it would default-initialize the unused buttons - so it would mean your button needs default constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not see the connection. How are they expected to use this knowledge? May be provide a snippet?

Comment: @SergeyA Well, I have to admit, what's _obvious_ for me doesn't need to be obvious for a beginner in the language. But anyways using a template should be the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by leveraging C++17's [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).  By turning `Screen` into a template that takes a `std::size_t` as a non type template parameter.  Then, by getting the number of arguments passed to the constructor you can use that as the value for the template parameter.  This then lets you make an array in `Screen` that is of that size.  This means that each `Screen` that hass a different number of buttons is a different type but you can have it inherit from a base class if you need to store multiple `Screen`s in a homogeneous container.

You can see that working with this minimal example

```
struct button
{
    std::string text;
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct screen
{
    button buttons[N];
    // constrain Args to only being buttons
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>, button>, bool> = true>
    screen(Args&&... args) : buttons{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
};

// get the number of arguments and use it for the array size
template<typename... Args>
screen(Args... args) -> screen<sizeof...(Args)>;

int main(){
    screen a{button{"one"}};
    screen b{button{"one"}, button{"two"}};
    screen c{button{"one"}, button{"two"}, button{"three"}};
}
```

---

The following code demonstrates how to use a base class and virtual functions so you can use a pointer to the base class to interact with different `screen`s.

```
struct button
{
    std::string text;
};

struct screen_interface 
{ 
    void virtual show() = 0; 
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct screen : screen_interface
{
    button buttons[N];
    // contstrain Args to only being buttons
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>, button>, bool> = true>
    screen(Args&&... args) : buttons{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
    void show()
    {
        for (auto const& e : buttons)
            std::cout << e.text << "\n";
    }
};

// get the number of arguments and use it for the array size
template<typename... Args>
screen(Args... args) -> screen<sizeof...(Args)>;

int main(){
    screen a{button{"one"}};
    screen b{button{"one"}, button{"two"}};
    screen c{button{"one"}, button{"two"}, button{"three"}};

    screen_interface* si = &b;
    si->show();
    si = &a;
    si->show();
}
```

Comment: Again, a matter of personal choice, but I'd do static_assert instead of enable_if (give no other signatures are available anyways)

Comment: @SergeyA Would you ever hit the `static_assert`?  Wouldn't `buttons{std::forward<Args>(args)...}` fail before the assert is reached?

Comment: This looks good; could a currentScreen variable like the one in my example be used along with this?

Comment: I think, you'd see both messages, and static assert might be more descriptive. But it is clearly a matter of personal choice.

Comment: You can but it will take some work.  You'll need to make `screen` inherit from a class and then have a pointer to that class.  Then that class can have a pure virtual function that you implement in `screen`. I'll add something here in minute.

Comment: @clyne I've added a way have a pointer to different `screen`s.

Comment: If I have these screens defined in multiple files though, I can't just have `extern screen a` in a header file, as I get an `error: class template argument deduction failed`. I could create a `screen_interface *siA = &a` for each screen and extern that, but is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @clyne I would suggest refactoring the code to get rid of the global objects if you can.  Global variables make the code a lot harder to reason about and should be avoid if at all possible

Comment: @clyne If you can't you should be able to mark the variable as `inline` and define it in the header file like `inline screen foo{button{"bar"}};`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with a template constructor taking an array by reference:

```
template<size_t size>
Screen(Button (&_buttons)[size]): buttons(_buttons), buttonCount(size) {}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
static Button buttonsForMainMenu[] = {
    Button("Do this"),
    Button("Do that"),
    Button("Exit")
};

Screen mainMenu(buttonsForMainMenu);
```

Note that because `Screen` just has a pointer to the buttons the array needs to live at least as long as the screen. Because of this I don't think there's a way to have a syntax like `Screen mainMenu({Button("Do this"), ...});` without dynamic allocations, since any temporary array would be destroyed after the constructor.